# Change the folder name for the directory WordPress is installed in

Tags: wordpress, directory

I just installed WordPress in a subfolder on my site (http://www.example.com/wordpress/) and I want to change the folder name from "wordpress" to "blog". I've already gone through the entire installation process, but have not made any customizations at all yet.

I tried just renaming the folder on the server, and the blog page does load, but some of the content was missing (the main, default header image, most notably), so I'm assuming there are other files that need to know the directory name as well.

If this is even feasible/possible without a complete reinstall, how do I change the folder name of a new WordPress installation?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you have to also change it in the database before you go changing the folder name.  Try going to `settings->general` in your wp-admin area and it'll be one of the first few input fields there.

So, change those two fields, save (the page might not come back however), then change the folder name.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick! I was scared for a moment when I made the settings changes, renamed the folder and then reloaded the page - I got a 404! But clearing the browser cache fixed that. Thanks again, Groovetrain!

Comment: This worked for mw without changing the database entry, just the settings and the folder name did the trick.

Answer (score 9):

Step 1 :

Go to settings->general and update your Site Address (URL) and WordPress Address (URL) to *http://example.com/new_folder_name*

---

step 2 :

Rename the folder name from *wordpress* to *blog*

---

step 3 :

Add this to wp-config.php file :

define('WP_HOME','http://example.com/new_folder_name'); define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com/new_folder_name);

Please clear your browser cache and relogin.

Comment: Is there a reason to add the definitions to the wp-config.php file?

Comment: Very Helpful.. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: It works if I follow 2 steps, (some parts of the website does work as expected), but if I define WP_HOME or WP_SITEURL, the website shows only white pages.

Comment: Really helpful steps! Step 3, however, seems to have been changed: no need to modify `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` (WordPress 5.4.1.) If you wish to change the database name to match, you need to put in the new database name (in wp-config.php) the line 1define( 'DB_NAME', 'new_database_name' )`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to touch the database settings. And all the instructions at codex (http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)  are overly complex. Believe it or not, ehow.com has the best step-by-step answer for this task:

http://www.ehow.com/how_6558163_changing-wordpress-directory-name.html

Comment: I believe its this easy because there is a function that executes on page load that updates the paths in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to WP admin dashboard
2. Go to Settings >> General
3. Change Wordpress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL)
4. Save. (After this step the page will refresh and throw an error)
5. In FTP or local, change folder name