# Changing Wordpress Directory Name

Tags: php, html, wordpress

My Site is Working well with url
www.softsystems.org/site&name
I wanted to make my site URL
www.softsystems.org/sitename
For this I cahnge Wordpress Directory Name site&name to sitename
but the site does not work,
I tried 2,3 times,Updated db Links,
I installed Fresh Wordpress, but no Success after 8-10 hours,

Please Guide me in this Regard so that I can get rid of this problem,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425042/change-the-folder-name-for-the-directory-wordpress-is-installed-in

Comment: you have to change some url values in wordpress database options table

Comment: I have done this,and all urls are changesd according to new link,

Comment: Did you make any modifications in htaccess file??

Comment: OK Dear I did not make any change in htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

I would try these 2 options :

1 - Go into Settings > Readings, set the Front page to a another page then save. After, put back the Front page to the correct page and save again.

2 - I would do the same thing with the Permalinks. Go into Settings > Permalinks and change it to something else and save. After put it back to what it was and save again.

This is what fixed it for me when I got the same problem.