# Changed WordPress Folder - All pages except homepage get error

Tags: wordpress

New to wordpress

I followed [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425042/change-the-folder-name-for-the-directory-wordpress-is-installed-in#) to change the wordpress folder name from "wordpress" to "aushadi".
Now only the [homepage](http://www.ayu.co.il/aushadi/) works. The other links get the following error:
"Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /wordpress/index.php on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."
I also followed advice and used [search and replace](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-and-replace/) wordpress plugin for replacing all "www.ayu.co.il/wordpress" to "www.ayu.co.il/aushadi" in DB.
Thanks

Update: Fixed by editing the .htaccess file. It was clearly wrong and easily edited. Hope this helps someone with similar problem

Comment: did you change the folder permissions?