# Change a wordpress theme folder name without affecting the website

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to rename my theme folder in the `wp-content/themes` folder, but it keeps breaking the site and meaning that I have to re-upload the logo, change all the colors again and etc.
It's a bit long and frustrating.

Is there any way I can rename the folder ( change anything in the database and etc ) which stops it from resetting settings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the folder name for the directory WordPress is installed in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8425042/change-the-folder-name-for-the-directory-wordpress-is-installed-in)

Comment: yeah you can, but of course, the theme still is using the old path name in any file, you need change it in every file

Comment: In general wordpress tracks file paths via its database. So you need the database paths to be updated as well, else essentially it will think the folder is a new site. Follow the answer in the duplicate post for a way to do this. Essentially you update the database path/name(s) and then rename the folder to match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can change the directory name of your active theme/child theme. The steps you need to do for Parent Theme:

1. Change theme folder name.
2. Go to phpMyAdmin, find your wordpress installation database, find the table `{your-db-prefix}_options`(by default it's `wp_options`) and find the `template` from column `option_name`. Change it's `option_value` to your theme directory new name. That row will look something like:

   ```
   option_id     |      option_name     |    option_value
   ---------------------------------------------------------
   {some_id}     |      template        |    twentyseventeen
   ```

If you're going to change the folder name of Child Theme, then instead of `template` you should find the record `stylesheet` and make same steps as for Parent theme.

This will prevent deleting Theme options from database.

Comment: I'd just add that he needs to also change the `theme_mods_<theme-name>` option in the same table.